# Deployment of Docker Container to CloudRun fails

Tags: docker, terraform, dockerfile, containers, google-cloud-run

I am attempting to configure an automatic deployment system which builds/re-builds a docker container to GCP's Cloud Run, from the Artifact Registry whenever any change are made to the source code. When I finally get to the last stage in my CI/CD pipeline (where container is deployed to CloudRun), I get the following error:

> │ Error: Error waiting to create Service: resource is in failed state "Ready:False", message: Revision 'containerized-model-ml-00001-98t' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8001 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

For context, here is the structure of my project and the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
├── .github
│   ├── workflows
│       └── ci_cd.yml
│
├── src
|   ├── backend.R
│   └── model.rds
│
├── terraform
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
│
└── README.md
```

**terraform configuration (main.tf)**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=0.13"
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "project_id-tf-states"
  }
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = ">= 3.0.1"
    }
  }
}

# -- Specifies GCP Project which Terraform will manage -- # 

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}



# -- Specifies the service account that terraform will use to manage infrastructure -- #
locals {
  tf_sa = var.service_account
}


# ----- Artifact registry to which docker containers will be deployed ----- #

resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "main" {
  project       = var.project_id
  location      = var.region
  repository_id = var.artifact_repository_name
  description   = "Repository for Cloud Run images"
  format        = "DOCKER"
  
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}


# ----- Define properly formatted variable names to be used as image address ----- #

locals {
  artifact_storage_address = "${var.region}.pkg.dev/${var.project_id}/deploy-ml-model/model"
}

# ----- Custom action used to call docker build on updates of tf configuration. Should only be ran once ----- # 

 resource "null_resource" "docker_build" {

     triggers = {
         always_run  = timestamp()
     }

     provisioner "local-exec" {
         working_dir = path.module
         command     = "docker build -t ${local.artifact_storage_address} . && docker push ${local.artifact_storage_address}"
     }
 }


# ----- Create GCP cloud run service on which to deploy our containerized ML model & API ----- # 

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
    name     = "containerized-model-ml"
    location = var.region
    project  = var.project_id

    metadata {
      annotations = {
        "run.googleapis.com/client-name" = "terraform"
      }
    }

    template {
      spec {
        containers {
          image = "${local.artifact_storage_address}:latest"
          # command = ["/Rscript", "./../src/backend.R"]
          ports {
            container_port = 8001
          }
        }
      }
    }

    traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
 }



# ----- Cloud run invoker ----- # 

data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
   binding {
     role = "roles/run.invoker"
     members = ["allUsers"]
   }
 }

 resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
   location    = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
   project     = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
   service     = google_cloud_run_service.default.name

   policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Install R-version 3.6.3 as image
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.6.3

# Install required ubuntu libraries for 'mlr'
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev r-cran-udunits2 libgsl-dev libgmp-dev libglu-dev  r-cran-rjags libmpfr-dev libopenmpi-dev

# Install required libraries
RUN R -e "install.packages('beakr')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('mlr')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('randomForest')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('caret')"

# Expose the used port from beakr
EXPOSE 8001

# Load Script with model
#ADD . /app

# set current working directory to the added app directory
#WORKDIR /app

# Run the R script that contains the application
CMD ["Rscript", "./../src/backend.R"]
```

**Actual app I want to deploy (backend.R)**

```
# source("model.R")
library(beakr)
library(caret)
library(mlr)



# -- Load the locally trained model -- # 

model = readRDS("model.rds")



# --- This function receives the 4 input values for the model that were sent in through the GET request 
# --- And then formats them into a dataframe which can be passed into the model for prediction 

get_prediction = function(arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, arg_4) {
  
  df = data.frame(
    'Sepal.Length' = as.numeric(arg_1),
    'Sepal.Width' = as.numeric(arg_2),
    'Petal.Length' = as.numeric(arg_3),
    'Petal.Width' = as.numeric(arg_4)
  )
  
  pred = predict(model, newdata = df)
  return((paste0("The predicted class of this plant is: ", pred)))
  
}


# -- Create API endpoint to receive & feed new data to model -- #  

newBeakr() %>% 
  httpGET(path = "/predict", decorate(get_prediction)) %>%    # Respond to GET requests at the "/predict" route
  handleErrors() %>%                                          # Handle any errors with a JSON response
  listen(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8001)                       # Start the server on port 8001
```

I have searched around for solutions for this specific error, and I have made sure that I specify an environment variable to expose the port 8001, which matches what is exposed in my container. I also want to emphasize that the container is successfully built and pushed to Google's Artifact Registry. I'm really not sure where to go from here. Are there any other suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: Your problem is here: `CMD ["Rscript", "./../src/backend.R"]`. Does that code start an HTTP server listening on $PORT? Note: `EXPOSE` does nothing in Cloud Run. Verify that your code is actually reading the environment variable PORT and starting the listener on that port number.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. When I ran docker build, the build was successful and the output suggested that the container was installing all necessary dependencies for my script, so I assumed everything worked as intended. I have edited my post and added the actual code from backend.R. Could the issue be that I am incorrectly specifying the path to my R code since it's in a different directory?

Comment: 1) What do the Google Cloud Run logs show? 2) Change all the port numbers to 8080. I do not see where you are reading the $PORT environment variable.

Comment: 1) `"terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /Rscript: no such file or directory"`


2) In the terraform configuration, I specify ports {container_port = 8001} and in the backend.R file itself, the beakr API instance being ran is configured to listen on port 8001

Judging by the CloudRun logs (which I somehow missed), i'm beginning to think its a matter of how I specify the path to my script. I've added `WORKDIR '../src'` and changed `CMD ["Rscript", "./backend.R"]`

Comment: Even though you are specifying port 8001, it is a smart practice to read what Cloud Run has set the port number to. Never allow your code to assume  (hard code) anything that can change. However, your first problem is that the file `/Rscript` does not exist.

Comment: Strange, I was following [this guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/05/26/hands-on-tutorial-manage-run-machine-learning-models-in-r-through-docker-and-in-sap-btp-kyma-runtime/), and I was under the impression that RScript refers to something that comes with rocker? Here is the [repository](https://github.com/SAP-samples/btp-kyma-runtime-startup-success-prediction) containing the code that the guide uses. Otherwise, thank you very much for the help and suggestions. I am still having trouble but will post an update if / when I resolve my issue.

Comment: EDIT: The /Rscript does indeed cause an error. This was a typo on my end and the forward slash is not supposed be there.

Comment: Your tutorial uses this command: `CMD ["Rscript", "./Startup.R"]`. Notice there is no `/` character in front of Rscipt. Start the container locally with a bash shell and find where `Rscript is located.